# Beautiful soup isn't showing the links

Tags: python, visual-studio, python-3.4, ptvs

I am trying to scrap an anime website for the anime episodes links and titles,
but the output is showing nothing or shows [] only.
This is the code am using:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('http://animeonline.vip/info/phi-brain-kami-puzzle-3')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
for link in soup.find_all('a',{'class':"list_episode"}):    
print(link)
```

Anyway, I suppose this will only list down the links inside that class. How can I show title beside each link?

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `div` has the class attribute, not the anchor tags, you were almost there

```
for link in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'list_episode'}):
     print(link)
```

Comment: that actually worked thanks for taking the time to check the website :D
now i only need to show both the link and title for that link

Comment: You could look through `link` again. i'm glad you got it to work....don't forget to accept my answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: can I do,
    href = link.get('a href')
    print(href)
?

Comment: no you can add an extra loop...something like, `for title in link: print(title)`...title will give you the individual divs